# Circular lists in guile

Tags: scheme, lisp, circular-reference, guile

I was testing this code in guile:

```
> (define xxx  (let ((x '(1 2 3))) (set-cdr! (cddr x) x) x))
> xxx
```

it display (1 2 3)

but this:

```
(define x '(1 2 3))
(set-cdr! (cddr x) x)
x
=> (1 2 3 . #-2#)
```

creates circular list

Why first code don't work in guile? If you don't know about guile I just want to know if it should work according to scheme spec, don't know where to search for such things.

Comment: *"it display (1 2 3)"* - again, no it doesn't. It throws an error: `In procedure set-cdr!: Wrong type argument in position 1 (expecting mutable pair): (3)`. What guile version do you use?

Comment: They produce the same, circular, result in Guile 2.0.13 [here](https://ideone.com/CQl54m). I believe 2.0 was pretty far from compliant with any of the Scheme standards, though.

Comment: Neither are valid Scheme since you are trying to modify constant quoted literal data. Thus if the implementation had printed `"BaNaNa"` it still would have been a OK.

Answer (score 3):

Problem with your examples is - they don't work. None of them. I have no clue how did the first one returned `(1 2 3)`. But when you fix the same problem in both examples, they work as expected and create circular list.

**Problem?**

`'(1 2 3)` and `(quote 1 2 3)` is something very different than `(list 1 2 3)`. They both "look" the same, but first one is static list and you can't modify it. Only list created with with `list` function (well and `cons`) is a list you can modify.

**Fix**:

```
(define xxx
  (let ((x (list 1 2 3)))
    (set-cdr! (cddr x) x)
    x))

xxx ;; => (1 2 3 . #-2#)
```

And the same goes for second example:

```
(define x (list 1 2 3))
(set-cdr! (cddr x) x)
```

Please test your code before posting.

Comment: Second code was working in guile, it was exact code I was testing, maybe `(quote 1 2 3)` work differently when using with `define`. Didn't know that `'(1 2 3)` is different then `(list 1 2 3)`. But if `quote` work differently then `list` then why this works `(let ((x '(1 2 3))) (append! x '(10)))`?

Comment: I was testing it also on guile (v 2.2.4). And I was getting an error. Don't know why your guile works differently.

Comment: Later guile got a memory protection and errors. Older version doesn't have this protection.